# page render dependent on async call

Tags: javascript, html

Typically when calling an asynchronous api to grab data the page depends on, I would:

1. Serve up the html
2. Use ajax from client to grab data
3. Show some sort of loading text/animation if necessary
4. Render content when the data is available

If I want all html rendered on page load, however, is there any good reason to not just do from the server (psuedo-code):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  _apiService.getData()
    .then(function(data) {
      //build html from template or whatever using data
      res.send(html);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      res.send(errorPage);
    });
});
```

In the style of a more traditional, synchronous, get data then return stuff way?

Obviously there's no fancy loading icon and instead that time is waiting on page load, but you'd get the fully rendered html and simplicity in return.

*question assumes requirement of async api

Comment: What is the question? Personal preferences, technical limitations, something else?

Comment: you'd lose the advantage of loading in (or reloading) individual chunks and the perceived load times would be significantly greater.

Comment: @Amit technical limitations

Comment: server rendering is/was better for SEO. if you can render the next page from ajax, that's pretty good...

Comment: @dandavis seo is certainly part of my reasoning behind fully rendered html being an advantage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of data you're serving.

If you're serving data that changes frequently (more often than a user would reload the page), AJAX is an ideal solution.

For example, social media data: users might post something while other users are waiting to see it. Thus, ideally your application would retrieve that data as soon as it was avaliable.

Otherwise, loading it from the backend is a simpler option, especially with data like blog posts: new blog posts aren't going to be coming in every few minutes and a small number users will have the page open when one becomes avaliable, so your application won't need to load it as soon as it is avaliable.

Comment: yes i'm accepting that this does nothing for data one may need/grab after the page load

Comment: @aw04 so does my answer help you? what are you looking for?

Comment: it does, thank you. i want to keep it open for a while to collect as many thoughts as i can and i will accept something :)